# How to connect PostgreSQl view with hibernate in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I do have a java web application, which does use Hibernate ORM for database connectivity. There are a lot of database tables, mainly configured as `hibernate xml mapping files` , i.e `hbm.xml` where each file is a table in the database.

Now the question is, - there are a view created with postgreSQl in the database and I want to use that view in java, how to do it? If I create another `hbm.xml` file that will be a table created in database. I've read over the internet there are examples on how to use it with annotations, but I dont have it configured in my web application.

Update1:

After some research and recommendation on below answer, this is what I have atm:

I created `xml` mapping file and a java class with getters/setters for each property:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"

>

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="org.xxx.model.SearchView" table="search" mutable="false">

    <id name="uuId" column="uuid">

    </id>


    <property name="typeOfCRA" column="typeofcra" />

    <property name="birthDate" column="birthDate" />

    <property name="lastName" column="lastname" />

    <property name="firstName" column="firstname" />

    <property name="middleName" column="middlename" />

    <property name="recordId" column="recordid" />

    <property name="registrationDate" column="registrationdate" />

    <property name="state" column="state" />

    <property name="organisationunitId" column="organisationunitid" />

    <property name="version" column="version" />

    <property name="gender" column="gender" />


</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is how I call it in java to get a list of results from database:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SearchView.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.like("typeofcra", "birth"));
List<SearchView> tmp =criteria.list();
```

It does'nt give any errors nothing. It keeps returning 0 records based on my criteria. But when I filter it out directly in `Postgresql` with the same criteria it returns almost 600k results.

During compilation or running this code snippet there are also 0 errors. Any help is appreciated.

Update2:

Hibernate conf file :

```
connection.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/finalDb
connection.username = postgres
connection.password = root
connection.schema = update
```

Updated code based on answer below:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SearchView.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.like("typeOfCRA", "%birth%"));
List<SearchView> tmp =criteria.list();
```

Direct call within the PgAdmin works:

```
SELECT typeofcra, dateofbirth, lastname, firstname, middlename, recordid, 
   registrationdate, state, organisationunitid, uuid, version, gender
 FROM public.search where typeofcra like '%birth%';
```

But from java it doesnt work.

Comment: are you able to fetch records with criteria? You need to modify your criteria query as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your hibernate mapping file posted above, you have `typeOfCRA` field in your `SearchView` entity. The issue is with your `Restriction`. If you want to perform `like` operation, you can do it like this

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SearchView.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.like("typeOfCRA", "%birth%")); //Changed code here
List<SearchView> tmp =criteria.list();
```

Above query will fetch all the records with `typeofcra` **contains** `birth` in it. If you want to perform case insensitive search you can use `ilike` restriction.

> Update

The issue is with your Hibernate mapping file name. Hibernate mapping file name should be same as that of your entity/class name. There is a spelling mistake in your hibernate mapping file name of SearchView class. Change the file name from `Searview.hbm.xml` -> `SearchView.hbm.xml`, it should resolve your issue

Comment: Exactly, I think it's because Hibernate keeps property names in HashMap, and property names should be case sensitive, so it must be "typeOfCRA".

Comment: it didnt work.. I think its something with configuration

Comment: @Daler can you post your updated code here. Also, share your hibernate config file

Comment: @Abhijeet, I've updated my code according to your answer. Also updated my answer with hibernate conf

Comment: Hey @Daler, you are still using your old code. Check this link `criteria.add(Restrictions.like("typeOfCRA", "%birth%"));`

Comment: @Abhijeet, no I've updated it according to your answer. I'm not running my old code

Comment: Hmm, what SQL query are you running on the database? can you share it as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193128/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-daler).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an entity for view and set `mutable="false"`,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.MyView" mutable="false">
       <!--properties-->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then use,

```
List<MyView> bvs = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM MyView v", MyView.class).getResultList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hibernate criteria always returns 0, but I can get the results from postgresql.. Doesn't seem to be working. any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use annotation, try the below link
https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-view-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

It can be mapped like an any table. Just define name and columns. Standard tables are not read-only, but you are not able to perform update on views. You can do that by annotating your entity with Hibernate's `@Immutable` annotation.

```
@Entity 
@Immutable 
public class MyCustomView { 

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false) 
    private Long id; 

    ...

}
```

Hibernate now will perform just `SELECT`, but not `UPDATE` if you change some value.